# Php 7.1 / Apache 2.4 / Windows - Openssl load error

Tags: windows, apache-2.4, openssl, php7

I want to upgrade my local server to php 7.1. When I try to do this everythings go fine except openssl.

With php <= 5.30 openssl works perfect but if I switch to php 7.1 openssl is disabled.

I think every settings is ok (http.conf, php.ini) because the same settings works with other php versions.

With php 7.1 I obtain msg like this: **Unable to find the wrapper "https" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP**

I tried to copy libeay32.dll, ssleay32.dll, openssl.exe in both windows folder and apache/bin folder I tried to add php dir to windows path I tried every possible way i have read on various pages, but nothing change.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue and managed to fix it. I found that the DLL relies on the files `libeay32.dll` and `ssleay32.dll` and figured that PHP7.1 being VC14 compiled it might be an incompatibility issue. Looking through my PATH I found that the directory `C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\` was the first directory to provide the file with an outdated version (1.0.0.17) as shown below (left is Intel's, right is the one bundled with PHP);

[image: libeay32.dll properties]

While I figured it might break the iCLS Client by causing the incompatibility error there, I took the risk and moved those directories below the PHP directory which (after restarting Apache) solved the issue.

[image: New PATH]

Comment: Don't work for me.

Comment: I have the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.
So I copied those files from my "old" PHP 5.6 folder to the PHP (7.2) folder (or for you maybe in the windows folder or wherever your path is). The files weren't available within my PHP 7.2 installation.
And it works perfect.